# Inability to view MathJax in Questions list in Android App

Tags: feature-request, bug, android-app, mathjax

I use the Android app of SE to access the site. However, I cannot see any MathJax formatting in the questions list:

[image]

However, I can see clearly MathJax formatted text when I open a question.

Is this a bug, or the feature is missing? In any case, it should be corrected.

*N.B.: I've used the example of Mathematics SE, but this is valid in any other site as well.*

Comment: TL;DR: this will never happen.